# Unable to mock useLoadScript in react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, jestjs, react-testing-library

[Here is the whole code in fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-jang-g1xs3?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx)

I am using `@react-google-maps/api` in my project which is using React, TypeScript and React Testing Library. I am trying to mock `useLoadScript` available in `@react-google-maps/api` but unable to mock it. Here is the excerpt code which I am using to mock it:

```
jest.mock("@react-google-maps/api", () => ({
  useLoadScript: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    isLoaded: true,
    loadError: undefined,
    url: ""
  }))
}));
```

I am trying to mock `useLoadScript` to see the case where `isLoaded` is true. To show this in as simple as possible way, I created a fiddle with example test case where I am trying to check the `TextField` is visible which will render only when `isLoaded` is `true`.

I tried multiple ways to mock the `useLoadScript` including the above try but couldn't able to mock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help others.

The issue in detail was even when I was mocking the `useLoadScript`, the test was still not mocking it at all. Seeing no errors and nothing, I was stuck.

The actual issue was the `MyComponent.tsx` file was using two properties of `@react-google-maps/api` i.e `useLoadScript` and also `GoogleMap`. But as you can see in my question, I was only trying to mock `useLoadScript`. Maybe since I wasn't mocking the in-use `GoogleMap`, the mock was failing silently (TIL). So, I changed the above code to the following, which passed the tests:

```
jest.mock("@react-google-maps/api", () => ({
  useLoadScript: () => ({
    isLoaded: true,
    loadError: null
  }),
  GoogleMap: () => <div></div>
}));
```

Also, I kept this mock functionality out of `beforeAll`. Here is the code to refer to on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-blackburn-ulxnd?file=/src/MyComponent.test.tsx). Strangely, the solution isn't working in CodeSandbox fiddle but working fine on my local.